# Запуск нескольких задач (Task) из Task и ожидание их выполнения

Tags: c#

Понимаю что делаю что-то неправильно, но может кто объяснит почему так происходит.

```
    private async void MainVoid()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (DriveInfo driver in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            var task = new Task(() => SomeDoWithDriver(driver));
            task.Start();
            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        //код здесь начинает свое выполнение не дождавшись WhenAll в тасках с SomeDoWithDriver
    }

    private async void SomeDoWithDriver(DriveInfo driver)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> resultSomeWork = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        var task01 = new Task(() => { resultSomeWork = IndependentSomeWork(); });

        IEnumerable<string> resultAnotherWork = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        var task02 = new Task(() => { resultAnotherWork = IndependentAnotherWork(); });

        task01.Start();
        task02.Start();
        await Task.WhenAll(task01, task02);

        //MainVoid завершается не дождавшись завершения =(

        ProceedWork(resultSomeWork, resultAnotherWork);
    }
```

Почему в MainVoid код после WhenAll() начинает выполняться до того завершатся все таски в SomeDoWithDriver()?

Comment: `async void SomeDoWithDriver` -> `async Task SomeDoWithDriver`; `new Task(() => SomeDoWithDriver(driver))` -> `new Task<Task>(() => SomeDoWithDriver(driver))`; `tasks.Add(task)` -> `tasks.Add(task.Unwrap())`.

Comment: @PetSerAl, спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция, что вы написали, не возвращает ничего

```
 private async void SomeDoWithDriver(DriveInfo driver)
```

То есть невозможно дождаться её окончания. Вообще `async void` не рекомендую использовать, только если это не обработчик события типа `async void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Чтобы иметь возможность дождаться окончания функции, она должна возвращать `Task`

```
 private async Task SomeDoWithDriver(DriveInfo driver)
```

То же самое про ваш метод Main (если вы используете [C# 7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1))

```
static async Task Main()
```

Далее, для асинхронной операции нет смысла создавать таск-обертку руками. Потому ваш цикл можно немного переписать.

```
private async Task MainVoid()
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (DriveInfo driver in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {            
        var task = SomeDoWithDriver(driver);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Ещё одно уточнение. [Не рекомендуется](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netframework-4.7.2) создавать `Task` через конструктор по причинам производительности. Если вам надо создать `Task` и сразу его запустить то используйте `Task.Run`.

```
private async void SomeDoWithDriver(DriveInfo driver)
{   
    var task01 = Task.Run(()=>IndependentSomeWork());   
    var task02 = Task.Run(()=>IndependentAnotherWork());    
    await Task.WhenAll(task01, task02);
    ProceedWork(task01.Result, task02.Result);
}
```

Comment: Не понял почему невозможно дождаться окончания void из-за того что он ничего не возвращает. Ведь если в SomeDoWithDriver не использовать таски, вполне себе дожидается.

Comment: @krok если функция синхронная, то дождаться `void` функции можно. Если функция асинхронная, то дождаться конца не сможете